# Drupal 8 show submenu on hover

Tags: submenu, drupal-8

How can i show my submenu-items in Drupal 8 on hover. At the moment they are visible all the time but i want they are only visible when hovering the parent-item.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You want to show submenu on hover of main menu. below are the modules you can use in drupal 8:

https://www.drupal.org/project/superfish

https://www.drupal.org/project/nice_menus

You can also control hover speed with this. Also these modules allow you to create mobile menu with same desktop menu thus are fully responsive.

Superfish menu gives many configuration for touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple CSS to show/hide on hover.

```
Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/n7J8x/5/
```